# How to install RTC on RPi3 with Kali Linux as OS?

Tags: pi-3, i2c, rtc, kali

I am using Raspberry Pi3 B with

- OS: **Kali Linux**
- Kernal: 4.1.19-v7
- RTC: DS3231 Real Time Clock

I configured I2C manually following the instruction [here](https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruits-raspberry-pi-lesson-4-gpio-setup/configuring-i2c).
Steps I did:

1. Install the i2c-tools utility

   ```
   sudo apt-get install python-smbus
   sudo apt-get install i2c-tools
   ```
2. Install Kernel Support

   ```
   #Open 
   sudo nano /etc/modules
   #Paste
   i2c-bcm2708 
   i2c-dev
   ```
3. Edit `config.txt` file

   ```
   #Open 
   sudo nano /boot/config.txt 
   #Paste 
   dtparam=i2c1=on
   dtparam=i2c_arm=on
   ```

After configuration and reboot, I tested it with

```
sudo i2cdetect -y 1
```

but getting the error:

```
Error: Could not open file `/dev/i2c-1' or `/dev/i2c/1': No such file or directory
```

What is the reason for the error? How could I fix this?
Is it even possible to install RTC on Kali Linux?

Comment: `sudo modprobe i2c-dev`

Comment: @goldilocks; I already added `i2c-dev` in `/modules` folder.

Comment: Sorry, missed that.  Check it is loaded w/ `sudo lsmod | grep i2c`.  Also check `ls -1 /dev | grep i2c`.  Both of them should output something.  The only required config.txt option is `dtparam=i2c_arm=on`.  Also, I would remove `i2c-bcm2708` from /etc/modules; technically the Pi 3 SoC uses a "BCM 2710" -- although I dunno if it matters WRT that module, just loading `i2c-dev` will pull in any required dependencies.  If you have done both those things (enabled in config.txt, and `i2c-dev` is shown loaded with `lsmod`), you should have a `/dev/i2c-1` node or something is wrong.

Comment: `sudo lsmod | grep i2c` shows the out put `i2c_dev 5654 i2c_bcm2708 5020`, but `ls -1 /dev | grep i2c` shows nothing.

Comment: I checked my 3 and it does use `i2c_bcm2708`.  All I can say is I've been using the I2C bus for years on B/B+/2/3 models and that's all I've ever had to do as far as I can remember.  **Try powering down, unplug everything from the pins, and reboot.**  If the module is loaded you should get the dev node and `i2cdetect -y 1` should work (but show nothing connected).  If not something may be busted.  Also double check `config.txt` to make sure nothing is overridden by multiple entries (and *remove `dtparam=i2c1=on`*).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, check that the `/boot/config.txt` you are editing is actually the on the first partition of the SD card.  Although it is not technically necessary, Raspbian is set up to mount this partition on `/boot` automatically, so online tutorials will refer to it that way -- and `raspi-config`, used in the Adafruit guide, presumes this is the case.

However, if the file doesn't exist it will be created, and if Kali doesn't use the scheme Raspbian does (comments here imply that), this means it will just create a file in the otherwise empty `/boot` directory, which won't actually be used when the system boots.  The Pi makes use of a vfat formatted partition at the beginning of the SD card, where firmware and bootloader must be located (and generally also the kernel).  You can set things up the same way by adding the following line to `/etc/fstab`:

```
/dev/mmcblk0p1  /boot           vfat    defaults          0       2
```

Note this will render anything actually in that directory inaccessible (but not delete it) although from the sounds of things there was nothing there to start with.

In any case, the contents of that partition -- `/dev/mmcblk0p1` -- should [resemble this](https://github.com/raspberrypi/firmware/tree/master/boot) -- and it must be there or the Pi would not work.  That github repo actually *doesn't* contain a `config.txt`, but whether or not there's one there on your system, that partition is where you want to apply it.  If you mount this before running `raspi-config` it should work out.  If you don't want it in `fstab`, manually:

```
mount -t vfat /dev/mmcblk0p1 /boot
```

> Kernal: 4.1.19-v7

This may be an issue.  It predates the release of the Pi 3 and may never have been updated for it.  Further, there is a Pi 3 specific device tree overlay in `/boot` and this implies you don't have that either.

You need to replace the contents of the `/boot` partition referred to above [with this](https://github.com/raspberrypi/firmware/tree/master/boot) and copy the `-v7+` modules directory [from here](https://github.com/raspberrypi/firmware/tree/master/modules) into `/lib/modules`.  It must remain named exactly the same.

Comment: Let me try. Will inform you.

Comment: I want to confirm that after copying -v7+ to /lib/modules do I need to remove 4.1.19-v7 or leave it as it is?

Comment: You don't need to remove it, but if everything works out it probably takes up 1-200 MB of space.  If you want to keep your old kernel/boot partition then back that up (the whole thing only has ~35MB in it) and leave the modules directory.  You can then put everything back as it was if necessary.  Unfortunately Kali may require some obscure IP features for certain things (I dunno), so that's not a bad idea.  If this works then those things don't, you'll have to compile your own kernel.

Comment: OK. I did the second step but I can see only  two files are in my `/boot` directory `cmdline.txt` and `config.txt`. Should I copy all the contents of `boot` directory of link you provided with the `/boot` present directory? And I don't want to keep the old kernel unless it is necessary.

Comment: Well you won't know if it is necessary right away, lol -- but it's probably easy enough to replace from a Kali image.  That is odd about the `/boot` directory, I don't know how they have their stuff set-up.  On Raspbian it's a mount point for the first partition, so you could just mount it where ever and look/change that way.  It has to be in the first partition or the Pi would not work; it's vfat, probably quite small.

Comment: Yes. Its a `vfat` partition of size `61.04` MiB (19.65 MiB is used). It is named as `/mmcblk0p1`. I mounted it to `/mnt`. Gave read/write permission, edited `fstab` and replaced all the contents of `/mnt` with the content of `boot` directory. But still getting the same error.

Comment: Okay, so here's the funny part: `config.txt` is actually read by the bootloader/firmware/kernel (not sure which, but probably one of the former two) *from the first partition*, so if you have have been editing a version of that file in your otherwise empty `/boot` partition, **it was not being used.**  You need to find the one on the actual first partition and edit that to include `dtparam=i2c_arm=on`.

Comment: Holy Cow!!! That's called holy mother of funny mistakes in programming. Finally it worked now. I would suggest please rewrite the answer with all these details. It will help future readers.

Comment: Alright -- done.

Comment: Great! But `raspi-config` will not run in Kali image. One must have to mount manually. And this `dtoverlay=i2c-rtc,ds3231` must be added to `config.txt` file.

Comment: Well, it probably could, at least for some things including this (it's only dependence is the shell and `whiptail`, which is pretty stock).  Anyway what I've said there will apply either way.

Answer (score 1):

The only thing you should need to do is to add the following line to `/boot/config.txt`

```
dtoverlay=i2c-rtc,ds3231
```