# How to add RTC as Clocksource on Raspberry Pi Zero running Rasbian

Tags: raspbian, pi-zero, rtc

Is it possible to add a hardware clock to available_clocksource in order to select it as the current_clocksource found in: /sys/devices/system/clocksource/clocksource0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think the item you listed has anything to do with `RTC`.

I recommend `DS3231`. This is simple to interface, and all the drivers are included. See https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/53395/8697

I may have misinterpreted your question. If you are proposing to use `RTC` as a system clock, this is still not possible, as most RTC only generate low frequency clocks.

Comment: Yes I was proposing the use of a RTC to replace the system clock. Thank you for clarifying the possibility of this.